# Shopware 6 - How to decorate ProductDefinition.php

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I've decorated the Shopware\Core\Content\Product\ProductDefinition.php class with dependency injection:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>

<container xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services/services-1.0.xsd">

    <services>
        <service id="MyPlugin\Core\Content\Product\ProductDefinitionDecorator"
                 decorates="Shopware\Core\Content\Product\ProductDefinition" public="false">
            <tag name="shopware.entity.definition" entity="product"/>
        </service>
    </services>
</container>
```

My own ProductDefinition.php extends the original and overrides the defineFields method:

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace MyPlugin\Core\Content\Product;

use Shopware\Core\Checkout\Customer\Aggregate\CustomerWishlistProduct\CustomerWishlistProductDefinition;
use Shopware\Core\Checkout\Order\Aggregate\OrderLineItem\OrderLineItemDefinition;
use Shopware\Core\Content\Category\CategoryDefinition;
use Shopware\Core\Content\Cms\CmsPageDefinition;
use Shopware\Core\Content\Product\Aggregate\ProductCategory\ProductCategoryDefinition;
use Shopware\Core\Content\Product\Aggregate\ProductCategoryTree\ProductCategoryTreeDefinition;
use Shopware\Core\Content\Product\Aggregate\ProductConfiguratorSetting\ProductConfiguratorSettingDefinition;
use Shopware\Core\Content\Product\Aggregate\ProductCrossSelling\ProductCrossSellingDefinition;
use Shopware\Core\Content\Product\Aggregate\ProductCrossSellingAssignedProducts\ProductCrossSellingAssignedProductsDefinition;
use Shopware\Core\Content\Product\Aggregate\ProductCustomFieldSet\ProductCustomFieldSetDefinition;
use Shopware\Core\Content\Product\Aggregate\ProductDownload\ProductDownloadDefinition;
use Shopware\Core\Content\Product\Aggregate\ProductFeatureSet\ProductFeatureSetDefinition;
use Shopware\Core\Content\Product\Aggregate\ProductManufacturer\ProductManufacturerDefinition;
use Shopware\Core\Content\Product\Aggregate\ProductMedia\ProductMediaDefinition;
use Shopware\Core\Content\Product\Aggregate\ProductOption\ProductOptionDefinition;
use Shopware\Core\Content\Product\Aggregate\ProductPrice\ProductPriceDefinition;
use Shopware\Core\Content\Product\Aggregate\ProductProperty\ProductPropertyDefinition;
use Shopware\Core\Content\Product\Aggregate\ProductReview\ProductReviewDefinition;
use Shopware\Core\Content\Product\Aggregate\ProductSearchKeyword\ProductSearchKeywordDefinition;
use Shopware\Core\Content\Product\Aggregate\ProductStreamMapping\ProductStreamMappingDefinition;
use Shopware\Core\Content\Product\Aggregate\ProductTag\ProductTagDefinition;
use Shopware\Core\Content\Product\Aggregate\ProductTranslation\ProductTranslationDefinition;
use Shopware\Core\Content\Product\Aggregate\ProductVisibility\ProductVisibilityDefinition;
use Shopware\Core\Content\Product\ProductDefinition;
use Shopware\Core\Content\ProductStream\ProductStreamDefinition;
use Shopware\Core\Content\Property\Aggregate\PropertyGroupOption\PropertyGroupOptionDefinition;
use Shopware\Core\Content\Seo\MainCategory\MainCategoryDefinition;
use Shopware\Core\Content\Seo\SeoUrl\SeoUrlDefinition;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\DefinitionInstanceRegistry;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\EntityDefinition;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Field\AutoIncrementField;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Field\BoolField;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Field\ChildCountField;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Field\ChildrenAssociationField;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Field\DateTimeField;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Field\FkField;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Field\Flag\ApiAware;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Field\Flag\ApiCriteriaAware;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Field\Flag\CascadeDelete;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Field\Flag\Inherited;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Field\Flag\NoConstraint;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Field\Flag\PrimaryKey;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Field\Flag\Required;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Field\Flag\Runtime;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Field\Flag\SearchRanking;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Field\Flag\SetNullOnDelete;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Field\Flag\WriteProtected;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Field\FloatField;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Field\IdField;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Field\IntField;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Field\JsonField;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Field\ListField;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Field\ManyToManyAssociationField;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Field\ManyToManyIdField;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Field\ManyToOneAssociationField;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Field\OneToManyAssociationField;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Field\ParentAssociationField;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Field\ParentFkField;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Field\PriceField;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Field\ReferenceVersionField;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Field\StringField;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Field\TranslatedField;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Field\TranslationsAssociationField;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Field\VariantListingConfigField;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Field\VersionField;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\FieldCollection;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\Feature;
use Shopware\Core\System\CustomField\Aggregate\CustomFieldSet\CustomFieldSetDefinition;
use Shopware\Core\System\DeliveryTime\DeliveryTimeDefinition;
use Shopware\Core\System\NumberRange\DataAbstractionLayer\NumberRangeField;
use Shopware\Core\System\Tag\TagDefinition;
use Shopware\Core\System\Tax\TaxDefinition;
use Shopware\Core\System\Unit\UnitDefinition;

class ProductDefinitionDecorator extends ProductDefinition
{
    protected function defineFields(): FieldCollection
    {
        $fields = new FieldCollection([
            (new IdField('id', 'id'))->addFlags(new ApiAware(), new PrimaryKey(), new Required()),
            (new VersionField())->addFlags(new ApiAware()),
            (new ParentFkField(self::class))->addFlags(new ApiAware()),
            (new ReferenceVersionField(self::class, 'parent_version_id'))->addFlags(new ApiAware(), new Required()),

            (new FkField('product_manufacturer_id', 'manufacturerId', ProductManufacturerDefinition::class))->addFlags(new ApiAware(), new Inherited()),
            (new ReferenceVersionField(ProductManufacturerDefinition::class))->addFlags(new ApiAware(), new Inherited(), new Required()),
            (new FkField('unit_id', 'unitId', UnitDefinition::class))->addFlags(new ApiAware(), new Inherited()),
            (new FkField('tax_id', 'taxId', TaxDefinition::class))->addFlags(new ApiAware(), new Inherited(), new Required()),
            (new FkField('product_media_id', 'coverId', ProductMediaDefinition::class))->addFlags(new ApiAware(), new Inherited(), new NoConstraint()),
            (new ReferenceVersionField(ProductMediaDefinition::class))->addFlags(new ApiAware(), new Inherited(), new Required()),
            (new FkField('delivery_time_id', 'deliveryTimeId', DeliveryTimeDefinition::class))->addFlags(new ApiAware(), new Inherited()),
            (new FkField('product_feature_set_id', 'featureSetId', ProductFeatureSetDefinition::class))->addFlags(new Inherited()),
            (new FkField('canonical_product_id', 'canonicalProductId', ProductDefinition::class))->addFlags(new ApiAware(), new Inherited()),
            (new FkField('cms_page_id', 'cmsPageId', CmsPageDefinition::class))->addFlags(new ApiAware(), new Inherited()),
            (new ReferenceVersionField(CmsPageDefinition::class))->addFlags(new Inherited(), new Required(), new ApiAware()),

            (new PriceField('price', 'price'))->addFlags(new Inherited(), new Required(), new ApiCriteriaAware()),
            (new NumberRangeField('product_number', 'productNumber'))->addFlags(new ApiAware(), new SearchRanking(SearchRanking::HIGH_SEARCH_RANKING, false), new Required()),
            (new IntField('restock_time', 'restockTime'))->addFlags(new ApiAware(), new Inherited()),
            new AutoIncrementField(),
            (new BoolField('active', 'active'))->addFlags(new ApiAware(), new Inherited()),
            (new BoolField('available', 'available'))->addFlags(new ApiAware(), new WriteProtected()),
            (new BoolField('is_closeout', 'isCloseout'))->addFlags(new ApiAware(), new Inherited()),

            (new ListField('variation', 'variation', StringField::class))->addFlags(new Runtime(['options.name', 'options.group.name'])),
            (new StringField('display_group', 'displayGroup'))->addFlags(new ApiAware(), new WriteProtected()),
            (new VariantListingConfigField('variant_listing_config', 'variantListingConfig'))->addFlags(new Inherited()),
            new JsonField('variant_restrictions', 'variantRestrictions'),
            (new StringField('manufacturer_number', 'manufacturerNumber'))->addFlags(new ApiAware(), new Inherited(), new SearchRanking(SearchRanking::MIDDLE_SEARCH_RANKING, false)),
            (new StringField('ean', 'ean'))->addFlags(new ApiAware(), new Inherited(), new SearchRanking(SearchRanking::MIDDLE_SEARCH_RANKING, false)),
            (new FloatField('purchase_steps', 'purchaseSteps'))->addFlags(new ApiAware(), new Inherited()),
            (new FloatField('max_purchase', 'maxPurchase'))->addFlags(new ApiAware(), new Inherited()),
            (new FloatField('min_purchase', 'minPurchase'))->addFlags(new ApiAware(), new Inherited()),
            (new FloatField('purchase_unit', 'purchaseUnit'))->addFlags(new ApiAware(), new Inherited()),
            (new FloatField('reference_unit', 'referenceUnit'))->addFlags(new ApiAware(), new Inherited()),
            (new BoolField('shipping_free', 'shippingFree'))->addFlags(new ApiAware(), new Inherited()),
            (new PriceField('purchase_prices', 'purchasePrices'))->addFlags(new Inherited()),
            (new BoolField('mark_as_topseller', 'markAsTopseller'))->addFlags(new ApiAware(), new Inherited()),
            (new FloatField('weight', 'weight'))->addFlags(new ApiAware(), new Inherited()),
            (new FloatField('width', 'width'))->addFlags(new ApiAware(), new Inherited()),
            (new FloatField('height', 'height'))->addFlags(new ApiAware(), new Inherited()),
            (new FloatField('length', 'length'))->addFlags(new ApiAware(), new Inherited()),
            (new DateTimeField('release_date', 'releaseDate'))->addFlags(new ApiAware(), new Inherited()),
            (new FloatField('rating_average', 'ratingAverage'))->addFlags(new ApiAware(), new WriteProtected(), new Inherited()),
            (new ListField('category_tree', 'categoryTree', IdField::class))->addFlags(new ApiAware(), new Inherited(), new WriteProtected()),
            (new ManyToManyIdField('property_ids', 'propertyIds', 'properties'))->addFlags(new ApiAware(), new Inherited()),
            (new ManyToManyIdField('option_ids', 'optionIds', 'options'))->addFlags(new ApiAware(), new Inherited()),
            (new ManyToManyIdField('stream_ids', 'streamIds', 'streams'))->addFlags(new ApiAware(), new Inherited()),
            (new ManyToManyIdField('tag_ids', 'tagIds', 'tags'))->addFlags(new Inherited()),
            (new ManyToManyIdField('category_ids', 'categoryIds', 'categories'))->addFlags(new ApiAware(), new Inherited()),
            (new ChildCountField())->addFlags(new ApiAware()),
            (new BoolField('custom_field_set_selection_active', 'customFieldSetSelectionActive'))->addFlags(new Inherited()),
            (new IntField('sales', 'sales'))->addFlags(new ApiAware(), new WriteProtected()),
            (new ListField('states', 'states', StringField::class))->addFlags(new ApiAware(), new WriteProtected()),
            (new OneToManyAssociationField('downloads', ProductDownloadDefinition::class, 'product_id'))->addFlags(new ApiAware(), new CascadeDelete()),

            (new TranslatedField('metaDescription'))->addFlags(new ApiAware(), new Inherited()),
            (new TranslatedField('name'))->addFlags(new ApiAware(), new Inherited(), new SearchRanking(SearchRanking::HIGH_SEARCH_RANKING)),
            (new TranslatedField('keywords'))->addFlags(new ApiAware(), new Inherited()),
            (new TranslatedField('description'))->addFlags(new ApiAware(), new Inherited()),
            (new TranslatedField('metaTitle'))->addFlags(new ApiAware(), new Inherited()),
            (new TranslatedField('packUnit'))->addFlags(new ApiAware(), new Inherited()),
            (new TranslatedField('packUnitPlural'))->addFlags(new ApiAware(), new Inherited()),
            (new TranslatedField('customFields'))->addFlags(new ApiAware(), new Inherited()),
            (new TranslatedField('slotConfig'))->addFlags(new Inherited()),
            (new TranslatedField('customSearchKeywords'))->addFlags(new Inherited(), new SearchRanking(SearchRanking::HIGH_SEARCH_RANKING)),

            // associations
            (new ParentAssociationField(self::class, 'id'))->addFlags(new ApiAware()),
            (new ChildrenAssociationField(self::class))->addFlags(new ApiAware()),

            (new ManyToOneAssociationField('deliveryTime', 'delivery_time_id', DeliveryTimeDefinition::class))->addFlags(new ApiAware(), new Inherited()),

            (new ManyToOneAssociationField('tax', 'tax_id', TaxDefinition::class, 'id', true))->addFlags(new ApiAware(), new Inherited()),

            (new ManyToOneAssociationField('manufacturer', 'product_manufacturer_id', ProductManufacturerDefinition::class, 'id'))->addFlags(new ApiAware(), new Inherited()),

            (new ManyToOneAssociationField('unit', 'unit_id', UnitDefinition::class, 'id'))->addFlags(new ApiAware(), new Inherited()),

            (new ManyToOneAssociationField('cover', 'product_media_id', ProductMediaDefinition::class, 'id'))->addFlags(new ApiAware(), new Inherited()),

            (new ManyToOneAssociationField('featureSet', 'product_feature_set_id', ProductFeatureSetDefinition::class, 'id'))->addFlags(new Inherited()),

            (new ManyToOneAssociationField('cmsPage', 'cms_page_id', CmsPageDefinition::class, 'id', false))->addFlags(new ApiAware(), new Inherited()),

            (new ManyToOneAssociationField('canonicalProduct', 'canonical_product_id', ProductDefinition::class, 'id'))->addFlags(new ApiAware(), new Inherited()),

            (new OneToManyAssociationField('prices', ProductPriceDefinition::class, 'product_id'))->addFlags(new CascadeDelete(), new Inherited()),

            (new OneToManyAssociationField('media', ProductMediaDefinition::class, 'product_id'))->addFlags(new ApiAware(), new CascadeDelete(), new Inherited()),

            (new OneToManyAssociationField('crossSellings', ProductCrossSellingDefinition::class, 'product_id'))->addFlags(new ApiAware(), new CascadeDelete(), new Inherited()),

            (new OneToManyAssociationField('crossSellingAssignedProducts', ProductCrossSellingAssignedProductsDefinition::class, 'product_id'))->addFlags(new CascadeDelete()),

            (new OneToManyAssociationField('configuratorSettings', ProductConfiguratorSettingDefinition::class, 'product_id', 'id'))->addFlags(new ApiAware(), new CascadeDelete()),

            (new OneToManyAssociationField('visibilities', ProductVisibilityDefinition::class, 'product_id'))->addFlags(new CascadeDelete(), new Inherited()),

            (new OneToManyAssociationField('searchKeywords', ProductSearchKeywordDefinition::class, 'product_id'))->addFlags(new CascadeDelete(false)),

            (new OneToManyAssociationField('productReviews', ProductReviewDefinition::class, 'product_id'))->addFlags(new ApiAware(), new CascadeDelete(false)),

            (new OneToManyAssociationField('mainCategories', MainCategoryDefinition::class, 'product_id'))->addFlags(new ApiAware(), new CascadeDelete()),

            (new OneToManyAssociationField('seoUrls', SeoUrlDefinition::class, 'foreign_key'))->addFlags(new ApiAware()),

            (new OneToManyAssociationField('orderLineItems', OrderLineItemDefinition::class, 'product_id'))->addFlags(new SetNullOnDelete()),

            (new OneToManyAssociationField('wishlists', CustomerWishlistProductDefinition::class, 'product_id'))->addFlags(new CascadeDelete()),

            (new ManyToManyAssociationField('options', PropertyGroupOptionDefinition::class, ProductOptionDefinition::class, 'product_id', 'property_group_option_id'))->addFlags(new ApiAware(), new CascadeDelete()),

            (new ManyToManyAssociationField('properties', PropertyGroupOptionDefinition::class, ProductPropertyDefinition::class, 'product_id', 'property_group_option_id'))->addFlags(new ApiAware(), new CascadeDelete(), new Inherited()),

            (new ManyToManyAssociationField('categories', CategoryDefinition::class, ProductCategoryDefinition::class, 'product_id', 'category_id'))->addFlags(new ApiAware(), new CascadeDelete(), new Inherited(), new SearchRanking(SearchRanking::ASSOCIATION_SEARCH_RANKING)),

            (new ManyToManyAssociationField('streams', ProductStreamDefinition::class, ProductStreamMappingDefinition::class, 'product_id', 'product_stream_id'))->addFlags(new ApiAware(), new CascadeDelete()),

            (new ManyToManyAssociationField('categoriesRo', CategoryDefinition::class, ProductCategoryTreeDefinition::class, 'product_id', 'category_id'))->addFlags(new ApiAware(), new CascadeDelete(false), new WriteProtected()),

            (new ManyToManyAssociationField('tags', TagDefinition::class, ProductTagDefinition::class, 'product_id', 'tag_id'))->addFlags(new CascadeDelete(), new Inherited(), new SearchRanking(SearchRanking::ASSOCIATION_SEARCH_RANKING)),

            (new ManyToManyAssociationField('customFieldSets', CustomFieldSetDefinition::class, ProductCustomFieldSetDefinition::class, 'product_id', 'custom_field_set_id'))->addFlags(new CascadeDelete(), new Inherited()),

            (new TranslationsAssociationField(ProductTranslationDefinition::class, 'product_id'))->addFlags(new ApiAware(), new Inherited(), new Required()),
        ]);

        if (Feature::isActive('STOCK_HANDLING')) {
            $fields->add((new FloatField('available_stock', 'availableStock'))->addFlags(new ApiAware(), new WriteProtected()));
        } else {
            /**
             * @deprecated tag:v6.6.0 availableStock will become write protected amd mirror stock from v6.6.0. It will not be removed for BC reasons.
             */
            $fields->add((new FloatField('available_stock', 'availableStock'))->addFlags(new ApiAware()));
        }
        $fields->add((new FloatField('stock', 'stock'))->addFlags(new ApiAware(), new Required()));

        return $fields;
    }
}
```

In the Shopware Administration everything works fine but if i try to load the Listing or product detailpage in storefront i got this error:

Definition for entity "Shopware\Core\Content\Product\ProductDefinition" does not exist.
Symfony Error (https://i.stack.imgur.com/g2BFj.png)

Looks like entityName is Class Path instead of "product" and i'm wondering why because the class extends from ProductDefinition that contains

```
final public const ENTITY_NAME = 'product';

    final public const CONFIG_KEY_DEFAULT_CMS_PAGE_PRODUCT = 'core.cms.default_product_cms_page';

    public function getEntityName(): string
    {
        return self::ENTITY_NAME;
    }
```

im grateful for any help

I tried to decorate SalesChannelProductDefinition too but the error still appears. Im wondering why the administration accept my changes to product fields for stock and available stock and storefront tells me that the entity definition does not exist. CMS Pages loaded successfully but everything related to product in storefront crashes with this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the data type of an existing field, like available_stock from int to float in the Product entity in Shopware 6, directly via a plugin is not a standard or recommended approach.

Shopware's architecture and database schema are designed with specific data types for each field, and altering these can lead to significant issues, including compatibility problems with other parts of the system, third-party plugins, and future Shopware updates.

However, as a conceptual approach, the process would involve the following steps:

**Add Custom Float Field:** You can add EntityExtensions or register to the product.loaded even.

**Migrate Data**: Write a script to transfer data from the existing available_stock field to the new float field during plugin installation.

**Update Logic:** Modify your plugin to use the new float field.

**Synchronize Fields:** You need to create a subscriber that listens to product update events. This subscriber will then synchronize the available_stock field with your custom field.

Comment: did you use any generative AI at all in the writing of this answer post?